# How to find the Fourier transform of $\mathbf 1_{[0,2\pi]}(x)\sin(x)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis

How does one find the Fourier transform of $f(x):=\mathbf 1_{[0,2\pi]}(x)\sin(x)$?

I have tried to use the definition from my text:

\begin{align*} 
\hat f(\xi) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)e^{-ix\xi} \ dx
\\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)e^{-ix\xi} \ dx
\end{align*}

It doesn't seem to lead anywhere. (*Anywhere* in the sense that, since we are decomposing sine, I was expecting the transform to be something simple). Is this the right way to go?

Wolfram alpha [returns](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+sin%28x%29):

$$i \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega-1)-i \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega+1)$$

If this is relevant to the problem: how does Dirac delta function come into play?

Comment: In the title of the question and in the WolframAlpha input, you ask for the Fourier transform of $\sin(x)$. But in the body of the question and in the integral you set up, you ask for the Fourier transform of $\mathbf 1_{[0,2\pi]}(x)\sin(x)$. These are different functions, and they have different Fourier transforms. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I'm interested in $\mathbf 1_{[0,2\pi]}(x)\sin(x)$. So would [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29+int+0..2*pi+sin%28x%29*exp%28-i*x*y%29+dx) be the correct answer?

Comment: Probably! The Fourier transform of a rectangle is a sinc, and the Fourier transform of a sine is a pair of Dirac deltas. So the Fourier transform of a rectangle times a sine is a sinc convolved with a pair of deltas, which equals a pair of sincs. From there, it's a matter of getting all the constants right.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Could you take a look at my comment to the answer, I don't quite see how to work it out her hand. (And WA seems to give something entirely different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*} 
\hat f(\xi) &  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)e^{-ix\xi} \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix-ix\xi}-e^{-ix-ix\xi} \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{(i-i\xi)x}-e^{(-i-i\xi)x} \ dx \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now simply use

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}e^{\alpha x}= \frac{e^{\alpha x}}{\alpha}|_0^{2 \pi}=\frac{e^{2 \pi \alpha}-1}{\alpha}$$

The dirac function comes from the fact that you asked WA to calculate the FT of $\sin(x)$ over the reals not restricted to $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: I did this and ended up with $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi(i-i\xi)}-1}{i-i\xi}-\frac{e^{2\pi(-i-i\xi)}-1}{-i-i\xi}\right)$$ and didn't know what to do next. WA [can't](https://tinyurl.com/p7nlgma) simplify it either. (That's basically, why I asked the question, sorry for not being clear enough.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll get much simpler! Each of the two terms could be written as a product of a complex exponential and a sinc function, if you prefer.

Comment: The only other possible simplification is bringing the two fractions to common denominator. The expression looks a tad simpler...